# Django thread's locale is not set

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with Django's middleware. I need to determine what locale to use in a Django's request handler.

All I got for now is that I get `get_language_from_request(request)`. 
If I send `-H 'Accept-Language: en-US'` in a header, this function returns `en`, for `-H 'Accept-Language: en-GB'` it returns `en-gb`. I of course have `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` installed.

However, I need something in this format - something like `locale.getlocale()` returns `('en_GB', 'UTF-8')`, but LocaleMiddleware doesn't update it.

Do you know how can I get this information from from Django?

Comment: Please explain what you need the encoding for?

Comment: @KlausD. I need to in order to pass it to a different component I call from Django. However what's really important is to get a region as well, so I'm mostly interested in `en_GB` or `en-gb`. So the thing that bothers me is that I get only `en` instead of  `en-US` or `en_US`

Comment: What you get there, is what the user set in the browser as languges. There might be more than one and they can have a language subtag and/or a quality value or not. The encoding is defined by the server. In Django it should be UTF-8.